# Can't connect application to database

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, jdbc, derby

I have a problem connecting my Web app to the database using Eclipses datasource explorer.

This is what I did:

[image]

Maybe i did configure wrong the driver. This is how i configurated the driver definition from eclipse Helios. Window->Preferences->DataManagement->Conectivity->Driver Definitions:

**1**

[image]

**2**

[image]

**3**

[image]

**4**

[image]

I am able to start the application server and even access the application throgh the browser. But i cannot interact with the db. This is how the config files of the webapp look like:

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="jdbc/GroupBuySystem">
<class>entities.Administ</class>
<class>entities.Buyer</class>
<class>entities.Comment</class>
<class>entities.Log</class>
<class>entities.Offer</class>
<class>entities.Seller</class>
</persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

**sun-resources.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0  Resource Definitions //EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-resources_1_3.dtd">
<resources>
<jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/myDatasource" object-type="user" pool-name="Derby_groupbuydb_userPool"/>
<jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="Derby_groupbuydb_userPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
<property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="PortNumber" value="1527"/>
    <property name="DatabaseName" value="groupbuydb"/>
    <property name="User" value="user"/>
    <property name="Password" value="pwd"/>
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/groupbuydb;create=true"/>
<property name="driverClass" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

Also i want to mention that i start the database from the console with this command:

> C:\glassfishv3\bin>asadmin start-database

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I connect to the DB?

Comment: Tnx :) i hope i find the way to fix this i am stuck with it and i cant continue my programming. Any ideas someone?

Comment: Can you connect to the server from another application? For example from `ij`, or the Console tool from the [H2 database](http://h2database.com)?

Comment: I'm wondering if you really need to specify the URL _and_ all the properties from the URL separately (server name, port, database name)... and if yes, if the 'case' is correct (lowercase `serverName`, uppercase `PortNumber` and so on).

Comment: Yes i have other apps that i can run on this server(but currently closed projects), as you see in image 1 each app has its separate data connection. I am able only to start the server and run the app in the browser. I dont use H2 console tool.

Comment: The file sun-web.xml i added as when i rightclicked the project-> new JDBC resource, all that info what came by default i think it is all correct.

Comment: This question would be much clearer and useful if the exception stack-trace was included *as text*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the wrong jar file. Use *derbyclient.jar* and not *derby.jar* for your driver.

*derby.jar* is for derby in embedded mode. *derbyclient.jar* is for network/server mode and that's what you have defined in your connection string:

```
<property name="URL" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/groupbuydb;create=true"/>
```